# Pack `INT` primary keys into a single `LONG`

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it efficient to "pack" two `INT` primary keys (a composite key) into a single `BIGINT` primary key? Can it be done automatically within mySQL or does it need to be done in the client (PHP, C++)?

I'm creating a directional graph connecting user IDs to one another (e.g. for a friend-finder) in mySQL.

MySQL supports 8-byte `BIGINT`s and 4-byte `INT`s, so the packer might look something like:

```
id_edge = ((BIGINT)id_from)*pow(2,31) + ((BIGINT)id_to)
```

How do the big boys (FB, LI) do it?  Is it easier or better to have three "independent" fields:

```
CREATE  TABLE `things`.`connections` (
`id_edge` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Need a single pk for gii\n' ,
`id_from` INT NOT NULL ,
`id_to` INT NOT NULL ,
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You shouldn't be seeking to micro-optimise the storage. Each column should store 1 piece of data - no more and no less.

If you implemented the packing you propose, you'd make indexing impossible - a full table scan would be required to find e.g. all rows with `id_to` equal to 19.

---

You can also read [Chapter 13 of the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/storage-engines.html), which discusses the various storage engines and how they actually store table data.

Comment: "*Each column should store 1 piece of data - no more and no less.*" - there's an exception, a [`SET` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all if you are going to do it with other than bitwise operators its never going to be efficient.

```
//assuming int is 4 bytes
$combined = ($a << 32) | $b
```

And even in this case it probably isnt worth the overhead.

Second is that size of int is different in different systems like 4 bytes on 32bit and 8 bytes in 64bit systems

I think MySQL already optimizes for the storage. Dont do something thats there for you for free.

Go for the simplicity or error will creep into your code.